# ¿Como quitar los caracteres \t y \n de una cadena en java?

Tags: java, json, replaceall

Tengo un String que contiene lo siguiente:

```
"{\"listPruebas\": [\n\n    {\n      \"nombrePrueba\" : \"pruebaA\",\n\n      \"id\" : 1,\n\n      \"tipoPrueba\" : \"PRUEBABASE1\",\n\n      \"elementoBase\" : \"tipoA\",\n\n            \"listaMarca\": [\n\n            {\n\n                \"elemento\": \"elemento1 \",\n\n                \"tipo\": \"ABC\",\n\n                \"cadena\": \"SFSG34235WF32\"\n\n            },\n\n            {\n\n                 \"elemento\":\"elemento2\",\n\n                 \"tipo\":\"DEF\",\n\n                 \"cadena\":\"DJRT64353GSDG\"\n\n            },\n\n            {\n\n                \"elemento\" : \"elemento3\",\n\n                \"formato \":\"JPG\"\n\n\n            }\n\n    ]},\n\n    {\n\n      \"nombrePrueba\" : \"pruebaB\",\n\n      \"id\" : 2,\n\n      \"tipoPrueba\" : \"PRUEBABASE2\",\n\n      \"elementoBase\" : \"imagenPrueba\",\n\n            \"listaMarca2\": [\n\n               {\n\n                   \"elemento\" : \"imagen\",\n\n                   \"tipo\": \"tipo5\",\n\n                   \"cadena\": \"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAA\"\n\n                }\n\n            ]\n    }\n\n\n\n            ],\n\n\n\n                \"listaBuscar\":\n\n                [\n\n                {\n\n                               \"tipoBusqueda\":\"busqueda1\",\n\n                               \"id\" : 1,\n\n                               \"operacion\" : \"operacion1\",\n\n                               \"valor\" : \"12\"\n\n                },\n\n                {\n\n                               \"tipoBusqueda\":\"binario\",\n\n                               \"id\" : 2,\n\n                               \"operacion\" : \"operacion2\",\n\n                               \"valor\" : \"13\"\n\n                },\n\n                {\n\n                               \"tipoFiltro\":\"numerico\",\n\n                               \"id\" : 31,\n\n                               \"operacion\" : \"MENOR_QUE\",\n\n                               \"valor\" : \"1980\",\n\n                               \"intervalo\" : 1\n\n                }\n\n                ],\n\n\n\n\n}\n"
```

Lo que quiero hacer es quitarle estos **\t**  y  **\n**   por que es lo que no me permite convertir ese string en un `JSONObject`, cual es la manera para hacerlo en Java??
Tengo lo siguiente pero no me funciona me lo pinta igual

```
String resultado = muestra.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `.replaceAll( )` realizando escape de el salto de linea y el tabulador,ejemplo:

```
.replaceAll("\\n","").replaceAll("\\t","");
```

incluso puedes reemplazar los espacios usando `.replaceAll("\\s","")` para tener la información más compacta:

```
   String resultado = muestra.replaceAll("\\n","").replaceAll("\\t","").replaceAll("\\s","");
```

o también:

```
 String resultado = muestra.replaceAll("\\n|\\t|\\s","");
```

de esta forma tendrías como resultado:

```
{"listPruebas":[{"nombrePrueba":"pruebaA","id":1,"tipoPrueba":"PRUEBABASE1","elementoBase":"tipoA","listaMarca":[{"elemento":"elemento1","tipo":"ABC","cadena":"SFSG34235WF32"},{"elemento":"elemento2","tipo":"DEF","cadena":"DJRT64353GSDG"},{"elemento":"elemento3","formato":"JPG"}]},{"nombrePrueba":"pruebaB","id":2,"tipoPrueba":"PRUEBABASE2","elementoBase":"imagenPrueba","listaMarca2":[{"elemento":"imagen","tipo":"tipo5","cadena":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAA"}]}],"listaBuscar":[{"tipoBusqueda":"busqueda1","id":1,"operacion":"operacion1","valor":"12"},{"tipoBusqueda":"binario","id":2,"operacion":"operacion2","valor":"13"},{"tipoFiltro":"numerico","id":31,"operacion":"MENOR_QUE","valor":"1980","intervalo":1}],}
```

---

Revisando la información resultante de tu cadena, en realidad tiene un pequeño detalle, el último "," no debería encontrarse para que tu información pueda considerarse un json:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente. el primer parámetro es la expresión regular que buscas que es \n o \t, la barra adicional que se pone antes de ellos es para escapar la barra.

```
String resultado = muestra.replaceAll("\\n|\\t", ""));
```

He hecho un pequeño programa y funciona correctamente con mi cadena de entrada:

```
public class Replace {
    private static final String BLANK = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String entrada = "412312412312\nfadsfafsd\tfdadfasdfa\n\t";

        System.out.println(entrada.replaceAll("\\n|\\t", BLANK));
    }
}
```

Aquí el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]